# Solspace Calendar - output day-by-day list of occurrence start dates

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar, events

I am really struggling to get the Solspace Calendar Module to do something that seems to me would be a fairly common requirement.

**Use Case**

- I have a travel site which is centered around package tours, and I've created calendar events for each tour's departure schedule.
- Tour departure events are multi-day, and have repeat rules to determine when the subsequent 'occurrences' will be scheduled.
- Typically a given tour could have a range of departures that starts in say, January, and ends in December.

**I need to output the following**

- day-by-day calendar template
- listing tour departures ('occurrences') for each day, for the next month or so.
- I do not want to show multi-day occurrences that **already started** as this is not useful information for someone who wants to join a tour at the point of departure.
- I would prefer not to use in-template conditionals to filter out occurrences that already started, because I'm dealing with a lot of data - over 300 tours with 5-50 occurrences for each - and this will be resource intensive, as well as pretty clumsy.

**What I've tried**

1. **{exp:calendar:cal} template tag** (and all other template tags) - eg:

   > {exp:calendar:cal
   >       date_range_start="tomorrow" 
   >       pad_short_weeks="n" 
   >       date_range_end="1 month" 
   >       first_day_of_week="1"}
   >
   > ```
   > {display_each_day} output occurrence start dates here {/display_each_day}
   > ```
   >
   > {/exp:calendar:cal}

   - Fails because it kicks out all occurrences that are **in progress** on the day specified, rather than just the occurrences that **start** on the day specified. So I'm seeing events that started before the date range, but are still in progress. Some tours are as long as 56 days, so results will be way out for a daily departure listing.
2. **Custom Query** - I was sure this would solve it, but no joy so far.

   > SELECT 
   >               exp_channel_titles.title AS t_title,
   >               exp_channel_data.entry_id AS d_entry_id
   >             FROM exp_calendar_events_occurrences
   >               LEFT JOIN exp_calendar_events ON exp_calendar_events_occurrences.event_id =
   >   exp_calendar_events.event_id
   >               LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles  ON exp_calendar_events_occurrences.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id
   >               LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data    ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id              = exp_channel_data.entry_id 
   >             WHERE exp_calendar_events_occurrences.start_date   = '{date format="%Y%m%d"}' 
   >               AND exp_calendar_events_occurrences.calendar_id = '887'

   - this fails because the exp_calendar_events_occurrences table does not appear to actually contain ***all occurrences***. I'm guessing event rules are used by the module to output repeat occurrences that do not appear with this approach.

Comment: Just to summarize in other words: you're looking to loop through each day, and **chronologically** display only events whose **first*** occurrence falls on that day. In other words, if I'm looking at April 10th, an event whose first occurrence is on April 10th will display, but an event that repeats daily, from April 7 to 12, for example, would not display. Is that correct? If so, your first strategy of using `{exp:calendar:cal}` might be good, and I can elaborate in an answer (sorry, might require a conditional).

Comment: Yes - loop through each day, but no, I want to display **any  occurrence**, but only if it **starts** on the day in question. At the moment I am getting any occurrence that **starts, ends or is in progress** on that day. My users are only interested in start dates, as these are **multi-day events** (tours) that depart from the listing location.

Comment: This use-case would of course also apply to many other scenarios - multi-day conferences, festivals, basically anything where the critical date to list by is the start date, and anything thereafter is not meaningful in the context of an 'upcoming events' type listing.

Answer (score 1):

`{exp:calendar:cal}` has the following tags that could be used:

- {event_**start**_date}, which displays the occurrence's start date.
- {event_**first**_date}, which displays the date of the event entry's **first** occurrence.

For example, if you have an event that starts and ends on April 11th, and repeats daily until April 17th, {event_first_date} will be April 11, but {event_start_date} will display the start date of each looping occurrence (April 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17).

In your situation you need to check if {event_first_date} isn't *before* the first day of your {exp:calendar:cal} timeframe. For example:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
     date_range_start="2014-04-11" 
     date_range_end="2014-04-17" 
     pad_short_weeks="n"}
  {display_each_day}
    {events}
       {if '{event_first_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}' >= '2014-04-11'}
           // Show occurrence data
       {/if}
    {/events}
  {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

This will only display the occurrence if the event's **first** occurrence is on or after 2014-04-11. (You can tweak the conditional to check for {event_**last**_date} and the last day of your range as well if needed)

You might now think: "*Great! But how to make the "2014-04-11" part dynamic?*"

You can do this by using the `{exp:calendar:date}` tag: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/date/

For example:

```
{exp:calendar:date base_date="today" output_date="today"}{date format="%Y-%m-%d"}{/exp:calendar:date}
```

This would turn the {exp:calendar:cal} above to something like this:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
     date_range_start="today" 
     date_range_end="+7 days" 
     pad_short_weeks="n"}
  {display_each_day}
    {events}
       {if '{event_first_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}' >= '{exp:calendar:date base_date="today" output_date="today"}{date format="%Y-%m-%d"}{/exp:calendar:date}'}
           // Show occurrence data
       {/if}
    {/events}
  {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```